# Trouble with Volley Library

Tags: android, android-volley

I try to get response in my application, when I try to call API using volley library, it's giving `com.android.volley.ServerError` and response code 400.
Here is my code

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    try
    {
        //start bottom
        String url="http://api.tektravels.com/BookingEngineService_Air/AirService.svc/rest/GetBookingDetails";
        url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        //String url="http://api.tektravels.com/BookingEngineService_Air/AirService.svc/rest/Search/";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("EndUserIp","216.10.251.69");
        jsonObject.put("TokenId","0307b931-bd7d-4860-9c4d-4d65103ebddc");
        jsonObject.put("PNR","ZERD8U");
        jsonObject.put("BookingId","1401272");
        Log.i("JsonObject",jsonObject.toString());
        JsonObjectRequest jsonobjectreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,jsonObject,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                    {
                        Log.i("response",response.toString());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
```

It is working in postman.The error i got

```
com.android.volley.ServerError
```

The Log is

```
10-12 10:34:19.525 7149-7189/com.farehawker E/Volley: [387] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://api.tektravels.com/BookingEngineService_Air/AirService.svc/rest/GetBookingDetails
10-12 10:34:19.529 7149-7149/com.farehawker I/Error: com.android.volley.ServerError
```

- The json I am sending is

  {"EndUserIp":"216.10.251.69","TokenId":"0307b931-bd7d-4860-9c4d-4d65103ebddc","PNR":"ZERD8U","BookingId":"1401272"}

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVHu9.png)
[Postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD5MX.png)

Comment: 400 means that your server is down

Comment: You need to post the code snippet of API call and proper log from logcat.

Comment: @Sushil Kumar But it is working on postman.

Comment: show your code and also error logcat

Comment: @Jay I posted my Log and api call

Comment: @user1 Check if you have to add any required header in your code

Comment: show your postman screenshot also.

Comment: @Parul How can i check that?

Comment: @user1 Verify it with postman. As Tejas said, share your postman's screenshot

Comment: @Parul I have shared postman screen shot

Comment: @user1 Append "/" at the end of your url

Comment: @Parul I appended "/" at the end of url but it did not work

Comment: You changed your url from "http://api.tektravels.com/BookingEngineService_Air/AirService.svc/rest/GetBookingDetails" to "http://api.tektravels.com/BookingEngineService_Air/AirService.svc/rest/GetBookingDetails/"

Comment: @Parul String url="http://api.tektravels.com/BookingEngineService_Air/AirService.svc/rest/GetBookingDetails/";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your requestqueuw with below one:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        try {
            String url = "http://api.tektravels.com/BookingEngineService_Air/AirService.svc/rest/GetBookingDetails/";
            url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("EndUserIp", "216.10.251.69");
            jsonObject.put("TokenId", "0307b931-bd7d-4860-9c4d-4d65103ebddc");
            jsonObject.put("PNR", "ZERD8U");
            jsonObject.put("BookingId", "1401272");
            Log.i("JsonObject", jsonObject.toString());
            JsonObjectRequest jsonobjectreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.i("response", response.toString());
                            //progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    },
                    // The final parameter overrides the method onErrorResponse() and passes VolleyError
                    //as a parameter
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                        }
                    }


            ) ;
 jsonobjectreq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    5000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            jsonobjectreq.setShouldCache(false);
            requestQueue.add(jsonobjectreq);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: In this code, I have only appended "/" at the end of url. I don't know , why it didn't work for you earlier.

Comment: why is it necessay to append / at the end of url?

Comment: Thanks for help.Can i have your email or whatsapp no

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you're sending **JsonObjectRequest**  to the server and for that, you need to pass **Content-Type** also with your Volley network call .

In your Volley NetworkCall Attach this **header** .

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    return headers;
}
```

Comment: I think JsonObjectRequest  will automatically add "application/json" as header.

Comment: yes @Parul but I want to be sure that he's passing a proper request to the server . and we can't figure out problem until he posts some other detail also

Comment: Issue is volley do not support redirecting url. And the url is internally redirecting to new url with "/" at end. So @user1 Download Volley code from https://github.com/samkirton/android-volley and add it as module. I think redirect issue is solved in this code.